# Compile for mixed platform (32, 64) and reference a 32 or 64 bit DLL resolved at runtime

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Using VS2010 under windows 32 or 64 bit.
Our C# app calls a 3rd party DLL (managed) that interfaces to an unmanaged DLL.
The 3rd party DLL API appears identical in 32 or 64 bit although underneath it links to a 32 or 64 bit unmanaged DLL.

We want our C# app to run on either 32 or 64 bit OS, ideally it will auto detect the OS and load the appropriate 32rd party DLL - via a simple factory class which tests the Enviroment. So the neatest solution would be a runtime folder containing:
  OurApp.exe 3rdParty32.DLL 3rdPartyUnmanaged32.DLL 3rdParty64.DLL 3rdPartyUnmanaged64.DLL

However, the interface for the managed 3rdParty 32 and 64 dll is identical so both cannot be referenced within the same VS2010 project: when adding the second the warning triangle is shown and it does not get referenced.

Is my only answer to create two extra library DLL projects to reference the 3rdParty 32 and 64 Dlls? So I would end up with this project arrangement:
Project 1:  Builds OurApp.exe, dynamically creates an object for project2 or project3.
Project 2:  Builds OurApp32.DLL which references 3rdParty32.dll
Project 3:  Builds OurApp64.DLL which references 3rdParty64.dll

Answer (score 5):

Since you have unmanaged code that is 32 bit or 64 bit specific, you lose the advantage of managed code being able to JIT into either mode at runtime.  It might be simplest just to set up your make file to build your application twice, once for 64 bit and once for 32 bit, and use conditional sections in the csproj file to reference the 32 bit or 64 bit unmanaged DLLs.  Let the installer install the binaries appropriate to the platform as found at install time.

Comment: +1 for simple common sense solution.  Logically different architectures should have different builds.  The target machine's OS isn't going to magically change from 32bit to 64bit neither should your software.  Let the installer determine what needs to be deployed that's what installs are for.

Answer (score 0):

I cant say I have done this before but a quick search tells me you can program against an interface and load the library dynamically via reflection.

Have you considered this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea, which should be possible by customizing your build process:

Have your project compile twice to YourApp32.exe and YourApp64.exe, modifying the references appropriately. Then also make a 3rd project with a bootstrapper YourApp.exe, which will only check the bit-ness of the system and load either YourApp32.exe or YourApp64.exe.

Naturally, this should probably be done only for release builds, because you effectively double your compile time, which will be annoying for the developers.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use reflection in your factory to load the corrected 3rd party assembly at run time, and create an instance of the proper class, and return a reference to that. Then you can just put the assemblies in the same directory as your executable, and load the proper one at runtime, without adding a project reference. However, typically this uses either a known base abstract class or interface from another assembly (Typically one devoted to just holding the needed declarations). It does not sound like you have this.

However, depending on the complexity of the type hierarchy of the 3rd party managed DLL, there could be an option along this route, with slightly more work.

1. Create a set of classes in your own project that mirror the 3rd party dll's structure. Assuming the third party library isn't too complex, this will probably be just one class with many methods. You would also have to recreate any structures passed back and forth, if any.
2. Create a set of delegates that match the signatures of the methods to be called in the dll. For example, a method such as:`string DoFoo(int a, int b)` would have a delegate something like `delegate string DoFooDelegate(int a, int b)`. If methods have the same signature, you can use a single delegate for all of those. Add to your set of classes created before a variable for each method to be called in the 3rd party DLL. So your classes would have a set of members along the lines of `private DoFooDelegate doFoo;`. Then can be whatever access level you deem appropriate.
3. For the most tedious part (Though you could probably do most of this with generic functions to assist). Using this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976.aspx and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74x8f551.aspx as a guide, create an instance of the wrapper classes, wire up each method from the 3rd party library to it's matching member in your classes. This should be done within your factory. Once done, return the new instance. You should then be able to call into the 3rd party assembly through your wrapper classes.

This is a very hacky way of doing this. If you have the option, get ahold of the 3rd party supplying the DLLs and see if you can convince them to expose either abstract classes or interfaces matching their two DLLs into a third assembly, then you can reference that, without all of the mucking around with delegates.